# appending a df to new row of csv file adds a empty row between added data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to append this single rowed df

```
rndList = ["albert", "magnus", "calc", 2, 5, "drop"]

rndListDf = pd.DataFrame([rndList])
```

to a new row of this csv file ,

```
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
```

to place each value under the corespondent column header

using this aproach

```
rndListDf.to_csv('./rnd_data.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

leaves a empty row between header and data in the csv file

how can I append the row without the empty row ?

```
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth


0,albert,magnus,calc,2,5,drop
```

Comment: It's only because you have empty lines after your header rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have empty lines after your header rows but you can try:

```
data = pd.read_csv('./rnd_data.csv')
rndListDf.rename(columns=dict(zip(rndListDf.columns, data.columns))) \
         .to_csv('./rnd_data.csv', index=False)
```

Content of your file after this operation:

```
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
albert,magnus,calc,2,5,drop
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested. Code or `pandas.to_csv` doesn't append new line. It comes from your original `csv` file. If you are trying to figure out how to add heading to your dataframe:

```
rndList = ["albert", "magnus", "calc", 2, 5, "drop"]
rndListDf = pd.DataFrame([rndList])

rndListDf.columns = 'first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth'.split(',')
rndListDf.to_csv('./rnd_data.csv', index=False)
```

alternatively, you can first clean your csv as suggested by Corralien and continue doing what you are doing. However, I would suggest to go with Corralien's solution.

```
# Cleanup
pd.read_csv('./rnd_data.csv').to_csv('rnd_data.csv', index=False)

# Your Code
rndList = ["albert", "magnus", "calc", 2, 5, "drop"]
rndListDf = pd.DataFrame([rndList])
rndListDf.to_csv('./rnd_data.csv', mode='a', header=False)

# Result
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
albert,magnus,calc,2,5,drop
```